# Is there some way to auto replace h\spaced equation labels with right marginalized labels?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I labeled my equations with numbers and separated the labels with H space function, but now I realise thus isn't so good, so I there some function that sets the labels to the right margin?

For Example :

\Vspace{}

$a=b$ \hspace {15mm} (3)

\vspace{}

So I would like to have the number equation labels marginalized, is there some function for that instead of align?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: latex `\begin{equation}` auomatically numbers the equation and places the number at the right edge, so it is hard to guess what you are doing with `\hspace` espcially as you have not shown your input or ouput.

Comment: I didn't use align but $$ and and v space to structure most of the equation clusters

Comment: It's still very difficult to guess what you're doing or how you're doing it. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: And you really should not be writing like that in the first place it is a huge fast of time and effort.

Comment: Oh, dear. You seem to not have had any lessons or readings of good practices in LaTeX. If you wrote like this a lot of equations, it will not be simple to write them properly with any `equation` environment. You gonna need at least to be smart with search and replace.

Comment: There aren't exactly any lessons online, this site is quite helpful but only for specific questions, I did write a portion in the align environment but that doesn't do anything for me and honestly it's a waste of more time along with other intricaseses like it goes all together to another page, and I don't want enumerated all equations

Comment: I think it's going to be fine this way, some equations are short so it felt weird that enumerations were all the way on the margins, so I added them with H space, it's not a crucial thing anyway